# Get text after specific text with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to get the full address from the below HTML code.

```
html_text = """
<div><h2 class="rounded">Address</h2><div class="textwidget"><p>30 Dov Hoz<br />
Kiryat Ono<br />
Israel 5555626</p>
</div></div>
"""
```

First I just want to search **"Address"** keyword in the HTML code and if it is there then I want to get all the text after **Address** keyword. I cannot use the class tag or any other tag because there are many classes with the same class name.

My code:

```
html_text = """
<div><h2 class="rounded">Address</h2><div class="textwidget"><p>30 Dov Hoz<br />
Kiryat Ono<br />
Israel 5555626</p>
</div></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
label = soup.find(text='Address')
print(lable)
add= label.next_sibling
print(add)
```

But I am getting None from the above code.

My desired output is like this:

```
Address
30 Dov Hoz
Kiryat Ono
Israel 5555626
```

Comment: lable is not the same as label. Also try find_next_sibling().text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.findNext("div")`

**Ex:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
label = soup.find(text='Address').findNext("div").text
print(label)
```

Or `next_element`

**Ex:**

```
label = soup.find(text='Address').next_element.text
print(label)
```

**Output:**

```
30 Dov Hoz
Kiryat Ono
Israel 5555626
```

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh. Exactly I was looking for this only.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using CSS selector:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('h2:contains("Address") + div').text)
```

Prints:

```
30 Dov Hoz
Kiryat Ono
Israel 5555626
```